# Two equivalent Required<> types are not equal

Tags: typescript

The assignment of `Required<T>` (where `T` extends `A`) to `Required<A>` does not work.

Here is a simplified example:

```
type A = { a?: number };

type B<T extends Required<A>> = T;

type C<T extends A> {
  b: B<Required<T>>;
}
```

From my perspective it should work, but I got `Type 'Required<T>' does not satisfy the constraint 'Required<A>'` error. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: why don't you use    type C<T extends Required<A>> ?

Comment: Thanks for the question. This is a simplified example, in real project I have more fields, some of them depend on A, but not Required<A> like this: type C<T extends A> {
  b: B<Required<T>>;
  c: T;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is not working is that by defining `T` with `<T extends A>`, a potentially valid type for `T` would be `{}`

If you slightly change your `type C` to be

```
    type C<T extends A> = {
      b: Required<T>;
    }
```

You'll see that you can use this implementation

```
    let c: C<{}> = {
      b: {},
    }
```

Comment: Ah, now I see. Thank you. Now I need to think about better solution for that.